# angularJs filter from in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

i have the following arry in my scope

```
 items: [
{
id: "0",
name: "כיבוי אורות",
roomId: "0",
type: "scenario",
status: 1
},
{
id: "1",
name: "הדלקת אורות",
roomId: "0",
type: "scenario",
status: 1
},
{
id: "0",
name: "תנור מטבח",
roomId: "0",
type: "heater",
status: 0
}]
```

i would like to filter it by id and type within  the controller ( not by ng-repeat | filter).

Thanks allot

Avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to filter by name and id from within the controller you could just use [native filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Look at the polyfill for support for older browsers.

```
var type = "TypeTOfilter",  id=idToFilter;
$scope.items = items.filter(function(itm){ return itm.id === id && itm.type === type  });
```

Or you could even inject ``$filter` in your controller, if you just want to do it one time, and not have it in the ng-repeat.

```
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', function($scope, filter){
     //...
     $scope.items = filter(items)({type:type, id:id});
     //....
 }]);
```

Or you could even do a for-loop to filter out items..